# Code keeps outputting blank text file after writing second function

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, function

I'm attempting to convert one text file into another, more organized version of that same file. So far I've been able to add newlines where I semi-wanted in the first function. I take an input file and spit out an output.

In my second function I'm using the output from the first fn as the input. I'm trying to use the fileinput library but every time I run the code the output file is blank. I also attempted to simply replace text and it's still outputting a blank text file. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
import re


def setup():
    input = open(r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work.txt', 'r+')
    output = open(r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_final.txt', 'w+')

    for line in input:
        output.write(re.sub('\s', '\n', line))  # This makes a line break after every Data unit.

    input.close()
    output.close()

def edits():
    input = open(r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_final.txt', 'w+')
    output2 = open(r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_final.txt', 'w+')

    for line in input:

            output2.write(re.sub('blue', 'TEST', line))


    input.close()
    output2.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
    edits()
```

[Here is an image of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1YJX.png)

Comment: Whenever the format is 'w+', you either create a new file, or override the existing one, starting blank.

Comment: Please don't use `input` as a name for the file object, as this hides the built-in `input` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! As Ann Zen said in the comments, I think your problem is because in `edits()` you're trying to read the lines from a file that you have opened in `'w+'` mode which will truncate (empty if you prefer) your file before doing anything with it.

I would also suggest working with an intermediate file if you really want to modify this file in two different functions. That would give something like:

```py
import re

def setup():
    input_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work.txt'
    intermediate_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_inter.txt'

    with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
        with open(intermediate_file_name, 'w') as intermediate_file:
            for current_line in input_file:
                intermediate_file.write(re.sub(r'\s', '\n', current_line))

def edits():
    intermediate_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_inter.txt'
    output_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_final.txt'

    with open(intermediate_file_name) as intermediate_file:
        with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
            for current_line in intermediate_file:
                output_file.write(re.sub(r'blue', 'TEST', current_line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    edits()
```

But instead of using a temporary file, you could use a in-memory temporary buffer using [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO). That would give something like that:

```py
import re
import io

temporary_buffer = io.StringIO()

def setup():
    input_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work.txt'

    with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
        for current_line in input_file:
            temporary_buffer.write(re.sub(r'\s', '\n', current_line))

def edits():
    output_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_final.txt'

    with open(output_file_name, "w") as output_file:
        output_text = temporary_buffer.getvalue()
        output_text = re.sub('blue', 'TEST', output_text)
        output_file.write(output_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    edits()
    temporary_buffer.close()
```

But the solution I would prefer is going through the file once and for each line do all the modifications needed before writing this line in the output file:

```py
import re

input_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work.txt'
output_file_name = r'C:\Users\Phillipos Admasu\Documents\India\india_work_final.txt'

matchers = (
    (re.compile(r'\s'), '\n'),
    (re.compile(r'blue'), 'TEST')
)

with open(input_file_name) as input_file:
    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            output_line = line
            for current_matcher, replacement_string in matchers:
                output_line = current_matcher.sub(replacement_string, output_line)
            output_file.write(output_line)
```

By the way, like Karl Knechtel said in the comments, don't assign a value to th name `input` because it's already associated to a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) of the standard library. You would loose access to that function. Others that would read your code could also  get confused.